# accessing Altering & querying Sql Server 2005 Table by a table-id or table-index

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-4.0, database-schema

Is there any way to address/refer to a SQL SERVER table, by its `Unique Index` rather its `TableName` **?**

my Application is using multiple `html` tables, which are acutally within a form,

for `CRUD` opporations,(more `R/U` than `Create` or `delete`) of an Existing `SQL` Table.

now... that i need to mix **two** separated tables, in **same** update-form (that's my first 'mix')

as i am using `Jquery` to pass parameters to  `C#` code behind, so it will take care of the 
update opporations, and will be able to differentiate the source of the update post/request

and i do know, i could address the table by its `TableName`,

i just wanted to make sure, as i was searching for some information on the web,

i've encountred results with the Terms `sql server 2005`... `table` `index` or `id`,

though all results seem to have something to do with, what i can call, some kind of "manipulation", in oreder to **create** some indexing system /schema (i think it's like `hdd`s has a `FAT table`)

and I Emphasize "Create",cause I was actualy looking for an existing /built in, numeric value for a "TableID", just the same as a `Table` has rows and each row has its row `IDENTITY` - Column.

so at this point  i am turning back to the real question at the top .

Comment: @MartinSmith i wanted to avoid use of strings and use a number to pass it to the Jquery Post function : onChange="Jupdate(this, 123)"
rather than "Jupdate(this,'tblNm')" which has it's nested quotes within a dubble quotes as my initial creation of this <input type="text"> is already being a generated string (kind a dynamic Html table rows generator that loops over `Datatable` rows/columns)

Comment: i need to implement a struct i think... that will be only within my code (C#) i see there's no answer for this in sql so i thought of Class or struct  `tablRef` , tableName=SQL schema tableName , tableID= just makeup one or create some logic to handle all table indexing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so that's what  i came up with aventually : a simple struct + a class to hold values for database

```
            public class DBMetaDetails
            {
                public struct DbTable
                {
                    public DbTable(string tableName, int tableId): this()
                    {
                        this.Name = tableName;
                        this.ID = tableId;
                    }
                    public string HtmlOutput;
                    public string Name { get; private set; }
                    public int ID { get; private  set; }
                }
            }


public sealed class tblsIDs
{
    public const int firstTbl= 1, SecondTbl = 2;

}
```

another class should be for table names

```
public sealed class tblsNames
{
    public const string  firstTbl= "firstTbl", SecondTbl = "SecondTbl";

}
```

another that will hold tables columns names ...etc